# How to prevent or replace weird characters in pasted Vim macros

Tags: vim, macros, character, paste, literals

When I record and paste a macro in vim, I end up with this:

```
<80>kl - these 3 characters (the <80> is just 1 character) represent <Left>
^[ - represents <Esc>
^M - represents <cr>
```

This is no good, as when I paste then to try to edit the macro, these characters not as legible.

I just want vim to paste macros using these more legible abbreviations instead of that cryptic nonsense.  Alternatively, a function that I can run on a pasted line to do the replacements would work fine.

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. What you're seeing are representations of the actual bytes in the register. `<Esc>` etc. is purely a convenience notation that can be interpreted by some Vim commands like `:map`.

Comment: Surely it's possible.  It doesn't have to be a direct replacement for paste - can just be a function that's run on a pasted line.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to clean it up? Is it only a comfort issue?

Comment: I often want to modify a macro that I didn't record right the first time, often save macros and map them to be used later, and sometimes want to later edit or extend those saved macros.  When they're long and full of what looks like garbage output, it gets difficult.  It's hard enough to interpret a vim macro with more legible characters.  Is it a "comfort issue" for programmers to not use machine code?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this but this hasn't been mentioned yet. You can generate ^[ and ^M using by typing `<C-V><ESC>` and `<C-V><CR>`. Generally type Ctrl V plus a non print key to generate the character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple function like this to substitute each occurrence (on the current line) of `^M`, `^[`, etc. with their replacements. You can add extra entries to the `replacements` dictionary as you find you need them.

```
function! ReplaceWeirdCharacters()
  let replacements = {
    \ "\<C-[>": '<Esc>',
    \ "\<C-M>": '<CR>',
    \ "\u80kb": '<BS>'
    \}
  for [a, b] in items(replacements)
    execute "s/" . a . "/" . b . "/ge"
  endfor
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>rwc :call ReplaceWeirdCharacters()<CR>
```

Comment: This works well.  How, though, do I represent the characters like <80>kb for backspace and <80>kD for delete?  There is a list of them using :help 't_ku'  -for mine and others' future reference.

Comment: You can literally put the `<80>` character into the script. (You can do this with `^M` and `^[` too) Or you can use `"\u80"`. (see `:h expr-quote`)

Comment: I'm not getting it.  I've tried `"\u80kb"`, `"<\u80kb>"`, a direct paste of the `"<80>kb"` from the macro, `"\ukb"`, `"<\ukb>"`, and many others, but it's not catching the `"<80>kb"` string that represents backspace.  Could you provide a direct/tested example of one of these characters, please?

Comment: I used `"\u80kb"` (see my edited answer) and it worked for me.

Comment: That's weird - I started disabling plugins, since it worked for you, and found that the tpope/vim-sensible plugin, installed through vundle, was breaking it for me.  I disabled that and now it works.  Thank you!